# VBA MS ACCESS - Login form redirect to different form based on selected button

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a login form:

[image: p]

Each button decides what source will be used by cbUserLogin ("Nazwa" on screenshot)

CODE:

```
Private Sub buttonUAP1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    Forms!MainLoginForm!cbUserLogin.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    Forms!MainLoginForm!cbUserLogin.RowSource = "queryUsersUAP1"
End Sub
```

And for each button the same code with the different query source.

I want to do something to actually decide where user will be directed based on that button.

If while logging in UAP 1 button is selected and login and password will match I want to land user in form_UAP1, if button UAP 2 will be selected while logging in I want to make user land on form_UAP2, etc.

I'm trying to bite that thing for already some days and I just can't find solution.

For now, while login and password match with query this happens (ofc. it works):

```
If Me.txtPassword.Value = DLookup("haslo", "dbUzytkownicy", "[Identyfikator]=" & Me.cbUserLogin.Value) Then

        compIdentyfikator = Me.cbUserLogin.Value

        'Zamykam formularz logowania i przenoszę do elementu docelowego

    Me.Visible = False
        DoCmd.OpenForm "test", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal

    Else
      MsgBox "Hasło które zostało podane jest nieprawodłowe", vbOKOnly, "Złe dane!"
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If
```

I'm using "hide" instead of cmd.close because I'm trying to pass compIdentyfikator to the other forms (they will be used later)

But 1st I want to bite that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a combobox control instead of a set of buttons. You could even use radio buttons to accomplish the same idea (if I'm understanding what you want). Direct your user to **Select UAP**, then when they click **Login**, you can read the UAP selection from the combobox or radiobutton group.

Create a Frame with Radiobuttons (named `frmUAP` in my example):

[image: Login form with Radiobutton group]

Then in your form's code, set up the Click event of the Frame group of option buttons:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub fraUAP_Click()
    '--- reload the combobox based on the user selection
    Me.cbUserLogin.RowSource = "queryUsersUAP" & Me.fraUAP.Value
    Me.cbUserLogin.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdZaloguj_Click()
    If (all_user_input_fields_have_been_validated) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUAP" & Me.fraUAP.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Your login Combobox should be refreshed every time the user selects a different Radiobutton.

**NOTE:** make sure the Radiobuttons (option buttons) each have the correct integer value in the group... `optUAP1` value = 1, etc

Comment: Whats the difference about radio buttons?
I mean, i just need something in VBA to actually change row source for cbUserLogin and change landing form after logging in.

This is not achieveable like this?

Comment: I expanded my example above. Hopefully that helps

Comment: We got little missunderstanding.
changing rowsource works good, I don't know how to decide about landing page, when user being logged in.

What I want to achieve is when user select "UAP 1" button, then rowsource changes (and it works right now), and when "UAP 1" button is selected ,if You click "Zaloguj" You will be redirected to formUAP1, in other case when You select UAP 2 button, if login and password match I want user to be moved to formUAP2.

I want these buttons to decide about rowsource of cbUserLogin (and i achieved that already) and about where You will be directed after You log in.

Comment: I will try to explain it a bit easier.

Buttons on my login form are radio buttons but with style of regular buttons :)

They do the job, i just dont know how to redirect users to particular form after they log in.

RowSource change works, what i don't know is how to decide where user will be directed after logging in.

If User select button UAP 1 i want him to be directed after logging in to formUAP1

If user select button UAP 2 i want him to be directed after logging in to formUAP2.

This is my problem.

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding you now... I added a method to open a different landing page based on your settings. Is this closer to what you're trying to do?

Comment: it was that easy? I didnt even think about such solution.. :)) I will check it in a moment and let You know.. i was trying to do it on 101 different methods and they were.. well.. too complicated. I mean, i made them hard and complicated.. ;)

Comment: That works just fine. Thank You for showing me appropriate way of thinking :)